# iptables ipt_recent recent module number of IP to remember

Tags: iptables

One of the parameters of `ipt_recnet` is `ip_list_tot` which dictates the number of IPs to remember.

What happens if it reaches that limit? Is it going to stop recording new IPs?

Comment: It sure seems like it would forget the oldest entries... I am not finding anything on Google, you may have to inspect the source.

Comment: It will replace the oldest entries with the most recent.  If the default (likely 100) is too small, you can increase it using options in modeprobe.d/ or you can split up your rules into multiple source networks to create more hash tables.